# Getting AssertionError when using proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, request

i am using proxy list for doing request in nodejs
there is my code

```
request.get({
    url: 'https://google.com',
    proxy: proxy[i],
    timeout: 1000
  }, function(err, res, body){
    console.log(err)
  })
```

i have 100 proxy
and some of them are giving me this error,
for example this proxy 89.20.135.204:80

```
assert.js:42
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 5 == 0
    at ClientRequest.onConnect (/Users/admin/Desktop/files/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:160:14)
```

How can i handle this ? if(err) next proxy , does not help